# dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, traversal

in how many way  i  traverse dictionary in python???

Comment: Didn't you ask this already?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006575/how-do-i-traverse-a-dictionary-in-python-closed

Comment: Also, it duplicates this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380734/how-to-do-this-python-dictionary-traverse-and-search

Answer (score 1):

Many ways!

```
testdict = {"bob" : 0, "joe": 20, "kate" : 73, "sue" : 40}

for items in testdict.items():
    print (items)

for key in testdict.keys():
    print (key, testdict[key])

for item in testdict.iteritems():
    print item

for key in testdict.iterkeys():
    print (key, testdict[key])
```

That's a few, but that begins to departing from these simple ways into something more complex.  All code was tested.

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, you can transverse Dictionaries in many ways.

A good read for beginners is located [here](http://www.diveintopython.org/getting_to_know_python/dictionaries.html).

Also a Dictionary might not be your best bet.More information would be helpful, not to mention it would aid in assisting you.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques

```
>>> knights = {'gallahad': 'the pure', 'robin': 'the brave'}
>>> for k, v in knights.iteritems():
...     print k, v
...
gallahad the pure
robin the brave
```