# Search for a key in a nested Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, nested

I have some Python dictionaries like this:

```
A = {id: {idnumber: condition},....
```

e.g.

```
A = {1: {11 : 567.54}, 2: {14 : 123.13}, .....
```

I need to search if the dictionary has any `idnumber == 11` and calculate something with the `condition`. But if in the entire dictionary doesn't have any `idnumber == 11`, I need to continue with the *next* dictionary.

This is my try:

```
for id, idnumber in A.iteritems():
    if 11 in idnumber.keys(): 
       calculate = ......
    else:
       break
```

Comment: **see also**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690/access-nested-dictionary-items-via-a-list-of-keys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're close.

```
idnum = 11
# The loop and 'if' are good
# You just had the 'break' in the wrong place
for id, idnumber in A.iteritems():
    if idnum in idnumber.keys(): # you can skip '.keys()', it's the default
       calculate = some_function_of(idnumber[idnum])
       break # if we find it we're done looking - leave the loop
    # otherwise we continue to the next dictionary
else:
    # this is the for loop's 'else' clause
    # if we don't find it at all, we end up here
    # because we never broke out of the loop
    calculate = your_default_value
    # or whatever you want to do if you don't find it
```

If you need to know how many `11`s there are as keys in the inner `dict`s, you can:

```
idnum = 11
print sum(idnum in idnumber for idnumber in A.itervalues())
```

This works because a key can only be in each `dict` once so you just have to test if the key exits. `in` returns `True` or `False` which are equal to `1` and `0`, so the `sum` is the number of occurences of `idnum`.

Comment: hi @agf thanks for your help. btw, what should I do if I want to count the number of 11 in idnumber?? THANKS!!! :)

Comment: I'm not sure of your question? `idnumber` is a `dict`, and `idnum` is a key in that `dict`, so there can only be one `idnum` in each `idnumber`. If you mean the total number of `idnumber` dicts that have `11`s as keys I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: sorry, I didn't explain correctly. those dictionaries are in a way that id is like a counting for each idnumber, i.e. like this `{1: {15: 67.4}, 2: {13: 78.4}, 3: {11 : 723.73}, 4: {11 : 34.21}...` so I need to count how many 11 are in all idnumbers in each dict. Thanks for your time!!! :)

Comment: @Alejandro That's what the code I added to the bottom of my answer does.

Answer (score 8):

### dpath to the rescue.

http://github.com/akesterson/dpath-python

dpath lets you search by globs, which will get you what you want.

```
$ easy_install dpath
>>> for (path, value) in dpath.util.search(MY_DICT, '*/11', yielded=True):
>>> ... # 'value' will contain your condition; now do something with it.
```

It will iterate out all of the conditions in the dictionary, so no special looping constructs required.

### See also

- [how do i traverse nested dictionaries (python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339859/how-do-i-traverse-nested-dictionaries-python)
- [How to do this - python dictionary traverse and search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380734/how-to-do-this-python-dictionary-traverse-and-search)
- [Access nested dictionary items via a list of keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690/access-nested-dictionary-items-via-a-list-of-keys)
- [Find all occurrences of a key in nested python dictionaries and lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807634/find-all-occurrences-of-a-key-in-nested-python-dictionaries-and-lists)
- [Traverse a nested dictionary and get the path in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929904/traverse-a-nested-dictionary-and-get-the-path-in-python)
- [Find all the keys and keys of the keys in a nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863761/find-all-the-keys-and-keys-of-the-keys-in-a-nested-dictionary)
- [Searching for keys in a nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625327/searching-for-keys-in-a-nested-dictionary)
- [Python: Updating a value in a deeply nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41157636/python-updating-a-value-in-a-deeply-nested-dictionary)
- [Is there a query language for JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777455/is-there-a-query-language-for-json)
- [Chained, nested dict() get calls in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484386/chained-nested-dict-get-calls-in-python/14484580#14484580)

Comment: This is a pervasive repeating question and `dpath` is hardly given enough recognition, despite it being a very straightforward solution, so linking here for better exposure.