# Find the child key(s) of nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary which is very similar to the one described [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19871956/2642361).

User arainchi posted the following function there:

```
def findkeys(node, kv):
    if isinstance(node, list):
        for i in node:
            for x in findkeys(i, kv):
               yield x
    elif isinstance(node, dict):
        if kv in node:
            yield node[kv]
        for j in node.values():
            for x in findkeys(j, kv):
                yield x
```

If I do

```
print (list(findkeys(d, 'id')))
```

the children of the given key as a generator object type are printed.

When I tried, listing down keys() by

```
print ((findkeys(d, 'id')).keys())
```

I am getting

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

How can I get the keys of the retrieved children?

Example:

```
cfg_dict = { 'mobile' :
                { 'checkBox_OS' :
                  { 'status' : 'None', 
                    'radioButton_Andriod' :
                      { 'status' : 'None',
                        'comboBox_Andriod_Brands' : 'LG'},
                    'radioButton_Windows' :
                      { 'status' : 'None',
                        'comboBox_Windows_Brands' : 'Nokia'},
                    'radioButton_Others' :
                      { 'status' : 'None',
                        'comboBox_Others_Brands' : 'Apple'}},
                  'checkBox_Screen_size' :
                    { 'status' : 'None',
                      'doubleSpinBox_Screen_size' : '5.0' }}
              }

print ("findkeys: ", findkeys(self.cfg_dict, "radioButton_Andriod"))
print ("list of findkeys:", list(findkeys(self.cfg_dict, "radioButton_Andriod")))
print ("keys of findKeys:", list(findkeys(self.cfg_dict, "radioButton_Andriod"))[0].keys())
```

Output:

```
findkeys:  <generator object findkeys at 0x02F0C850>
list of findkeys: [{'status': False, 'comboBox_Andriod_Brands': 'Sony'}]
keys of findKeys: dict_keys(['status', 'comboBox_Andriod_Brands'])
```

I want to iterate over the keys of the child. 
something like,

```
#pseudo code        
for everykey in child.keys()
  if everykey.value == "this":
    #do this
  else:
    #do that
```

Comment: `findkeys(d, 'id')` will return you list type object, and you are trying to get keys of list type of generator.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: That function you linked to returns the *values* for a given key, not the *keys*. Are you sure you want to get the keys? And if so, which ones?

Comment: @sreekang can you please add some example of output? So that we can understand exactly, what do you want.

Comment: @dinu - i have added an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list(findkeys(d, 'id'))[0].keys()
```

for keys of the first child found. It will bug if it s not a dict so you will probably need to check

edit : for what you ask in your new edit

```
for value in findkeys(d, 'id'):
    for child_key, child_value in value.items():
        if child_value == 'this':
            # do this
        else:
            # do that
```

Comment: Solution looks like `for everykey in list(findkeys(self.cfg_dict, 'comboBox_Others_Brands'))[0].keys():
        kvalue = list(findkeys(self.cfg_dict, 'comboBox_Others_Brands'))[0].get(everykey)`

Comment: if cfg_dict is an object attribute and findkeys a method of this object, why pass cfg_dict as argument ? perhaps it would be better to give the format of your data, what you want to do, and what you have for now, it would be more clear

Answer (score 0):

I've made a pypi package for this. You can refer here https://test.pypi.org/project/dictnodefinder/1.0.1.dev1/

Install it first

```
pip install dictnodefinder
```

Then use it like this

```
import dictnodefinder

source = {‘a’:{‘b’:0}}    
key_to_find = ‘b’

print(dictnodefinder.findkeys(source, key_to_find))
```