# Get the number of fields on an index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

For optimization purposes, I am trying to cut down my total field count. However before I am going to do that I want to get an idea of how many fields I actually have. There doesn't seem to be any Information in the `_stats` endpoint and I can't quite figure out how the migration tool does its field count calculation.

Is there some way, either with an endpoint or by other means, to get the total field count of a specified index?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To build a bit further upon what the other answer provided, you can get the mapping and then simply count the number of times the keyword `type` appears in the output, which gives the number of fields since each field needs a type:

```
curl -s -XGET localhost:9200/index/_mapping?pretty | grep type | wc -l
```

Comment: That is what I am looking for! Much appreciated!

Comment: Is this accurate if you have multiple types, since the fields could overlap?  Also, won't this count types in dynamic templates?  It seems like you need the count of the unique fields, since that is what lucene cares about.

Comment: @ChristianTrimble feel free to ask a new question referencing this one

Comment: @Val a field can have more than one "type": e.g. "datapath-id": {
                                                "fields": {
                                                    "keyword": {
                                                        "ignore_above": 256, 
                                                        "type": "keyword"
                                                    }
                                                }, 
                                                "type": "text"
                                            }

Comment: seems, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/54218379/5215544 is more correct.

Comment: @BaZZiliO now probably, yet the `_field_caps` API was not available at the time the answer was contributed.

Comment: This will not work if a field has been disabled for indexing with `"index": false` in the mappings. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html

Comment: @joctee it dos work because the field is still in the mapping which is what this command retrieves.

Comment: You are right. You get the number of fields in the mappings but you won't get the number of fields that are actually indexed. It's the number of indexed fields that you want to reduce for optimization purposes. And for that, this approach does not work.

Comment: Well, it's trivial to plug `jq` in the middle of the pipeline to filter out those fields.

Answer (score 30):

You can try this:

```
curl -s -XGET "http://localhost:9200/index/_field_caps?fields=*" | jq '.fields|length'
```

Comment: This is the correct answer IMO, not the accepted one.

Comment: Disclaimer: When the accepted answer was contributed, the `_field_caps` API didn't exist. Also, just note that counting `_fields.length` is not enough to know the number of fields though, as there can be sub-fields as well

Answer (score 10):

Just a quick way to get a relative estimate in **Kibana** without writing a script (I don't believe this is 100% precise, but it's an easy way to tell if your dynamic fields are blowing up to huge numbers for some reason).

**Run this query in the Kibana dev tools**

`GET /index_name/_mapping`

Inside the Kibana output, perform a **search** for all instances of `"type"` (including quotes). This will count the instances and get you the answer. *(In this example, 804)*

[image]

This can be helpful if you scratching your head as to why you're getting the `[remote_transport_exception]` error of

`Limit of total fields [1000] in index [index_name] has been exceeded`

Comment: Select the results and Press Ctrl+F to show the search box.

Answer (score 6):

The first answer by Val solves the problem for me too. But I just wanted to list out some corner cases which can lead to misleading numbers.

1. The document has fields with the word "type" in them.

For example

```
 "content_type" : {
   "type" : "text",
     "fields" : {
       "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
       }
     }
   },
```

This will match `grep type` thrice while it should do that only twice i.e. it should not match "content_type". This scenario has an easy fix.

Instead of

```
curl -s -XGET localhost:9200/index/_mapping?pretty | grep type
```

Use

```
curl -s -XGET localhost:9200/index/_mapping?pretty | grep '"type"'
```

to get an exact match of '"type"'

2. The document has a field of the exact name "type"

For example

```
"type" : {
  "type" : "text",
   "fields" : {
     "keyword" : {
       "type" : "keyword"
     }
   }
},
```

In this case also the match is thrice instead of twice. But using

```
curl -s -XGET localhost:9200/index/_mapping?pretty | grep '"type"'
```

is not going to cut it. We will have to skip fields with the "type" keyword as substring as well as an exact match. In this case we can add an additional filter like so:

```
curl -s -XGET localhost:9200/index/_mapping?pretty |\
grep '"type"' | grep -v "{"
```

In addition to the above 2 scenarios, if you are using the api programmatically to push numbers for tracking i.e. into something like AWS cloudwatch or Graphite, you can use the following code to call the API - get the data, and recursively search for the keyword "type" - while skipping any fuzzy matches and resolving deeper into fields with the exact name "type".

```
import sys
import json
import requests

# The following find function is a minor edit of the function posted here
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807634/find-all-occurrences-of-a-key-in-nested-python-dictionaries-and-lists

def find(key, value):
  for k, v in value.iteritems():
    if k == key and not isinstance(v, dict) and not isinstance(v, list):
      yield v
    elif isinstance(v, dict):
      for result in find(key, v):
        yield result
    elif isinstance(v, list):
      for d in v:
        for result in find(key, d):
          yield result

def get_index_type_count(es_host):
  try:
    response = requests.get('https://%s/_mapping/' % es_host)
  except Exception as ex:
    print('Failed to get response - %s' % ex)
    sys.exit(1)

  indices_mapping_data = response.json()
  output = {}

  for index, mapping_data in indices_mapping_data.iteritems():
    output[index] = len(list(find('type', mapping_data)))

  return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print json.dumps(get_index_type_count(sys.argv[1]), indent=2)
```

The above code is also posted as a gist here - https://gist.github.com/saurabh-hirani/e8cbc96844307a41ff4bc8aa8ebd7459

Answer (score 1):

You can get that information with the `_mapping` endpoint of the index API, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html

> The get mapping API allows to retrieve mapping definitions for an index or index/type.
>
> GET /twitter/_mapping/tweet

With curl: `curl [elasticsearch adress]/[index]/_mapping?pretty`

Comment: That just returns me all the fields I have and not really a count.

Comment: Oops. I misread your question. Sorry I don't know how to give a direct count.

Answer (score 0):

A field can have more than one "type": 
e.g.

```
"datapath-id": {
    "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256, 
            "type": "keyword"
        }
    }, 
    "type": "text"
}
```

We can ignore "type" within "fields" to get exact field count. One example is:

```
import json


def myprint(d, field_count):
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            if k != "fields":
                field_count = myprint(v, field_count)
        else:
            print "{0} : {1}".format(k, v)
            field_count += 1
    return field_count

with open("output/mappings.json") as f:
    d = json.load(f)
    final_field_count = myprint(d, field_count=0)
    print "field count", final_field_count
```