# number of mapped fields within an Elasticsearch Index

Tags: elasticsearch

I was wondering if there is a way to query the number of mapped fields within an existing Index! Is that possible? In general, I am asking because I want to know how to handle a situation where my Index is getting close to elastic limit which is `1000`.

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586020/get-the-number-of-fields-on-an-index

Comment: Wow! thanks a lot Adam :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://localhost:9200/twitter/_mapping and to get mapping information and later get the count of fields from properties or by counting how many times "type" is used.

Comment: Thank you very much Biplab :)