# Limit of total fields [1000] in index [index_name] has been exceeded.. need to reindex?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-7

I have run a indexing job that took more than 24 hours and now when i try to query the index via Kibana i get some mapping errors. Seems the ES logs had this error *Limit of total fields [1000] in index [index_name] has been exceeded*. i see the documents are indexed and also found the solution to increase the mapping but should i be deleting the entire index and start off again or is there a easy way around?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Limit of total fields \[1000\] in index \[\] has been exceeded" means in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55372330/what-does-limit-of-total-fields-1000-in-index-has-been-exceeded-means-in)

Comment: This thread mentions the solution to this problem but i want to know can i apply the solution to existing index and make them work or should i add the solution and start indexing the documents fresh again?

Comment: You can just updated index mapping and then try to search. it should work without reindexing. in above thread, they have given API to check number of field in your index so you can check and if you feel that some document or field might be missing then reindex is only option.

Comment: Do you receive an error in the reindex time or in the query time in the Kibana? If this error appear in the reindex time, i strongly recommended to check that all documents ingested into the new index. Regulary this exception doesn't allow to index the document