# List Multiples of the Same Variable only Once

Tags: python, csv

I have a python script that looks at a json file and lists variables to a CSV.  The problem I am having is latitude and logitude are listed twice.  Therefore, when I write the row, it looks at those variables and creates an output with duplicate values.

```
import csv, json, sys

def find_deep_value(d, key):
# Modified from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568649/convert-json-to-csv-using-python/48569129#48569129

    if key in d:
        return d[key]
    for k in d.keys():
        if isinstance(d[k], dict):
            for j in find_deep_value(d[k], key):
                return j

inputFile = open("pywu.cache.json", 'r')  # open json file
outputFile = open("CurrentObs.csv", 'w')  # load csv file
data = json.load(inputFile)  # load json content
inputFile.close()  # close the input file
output = csv.writer(outputFile)  # create a csv.write

# Gives you latitude coordinates from within the json
lat = find_deep_value(data, "latitude")

# Gives you longitude coordinates from within the json
lon = find_deep_value(data, "longitude")

# Gives you a list of weather from within the json
weather = find_deep_value(data, "weather")

# Gives you a list of temperature_strings from within the json
temp = find_deep_value(data, "temperature_string")

output.writerow([lat, lon, weather, temp])

outputFile.close()
```

Is there a way to only list them once?

Comment: can we see the code?

Comment: Revised question with code, posted.

Comment: Could you add a sample of the data you're loading too, please?  Basically it would be sweet if we had everything we need to just run it and see your problem on our computers.

Comment: I assume your `key` will always be in `d` so your problem is very likely in `if key in d: yield d[key]` since you always return the same value.

Comment: Do you know about [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) ?

Comment: I have not used set, no.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `return` rather than `yield`. Yield is for [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). Once you fix that, you'll also need to change

```
list(find_deep_value(data, "latitude"))
```

to

```
find_deep_value(data, "latitude")
```

for each of those lines. And finally, change

```
output.writerow(lat + lon + weather + temp)
```

to

```
output.writerow([lat, lon, weather, temp])
```

---

What's happening (you might want to read up on generators first) is when a key is not in the top-level dictionary, you start looping through them, and when the first `'latitude'` is reached, the `yield` keyword returns a generator object. You have that generator wrapped in `list()` which immediately unpacks the entire generator into a list. So if you have more than one sub-dictionary with the given key in it, you're going to end up looking through and finding every single one.

Comment: Thanks Dan for your response.  I understand what you're saying: list will parse the entire file and return all values matching keys.  I made the changes you suggested.  However, when running the code, I now get a "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" on the lat variable.

Comment: If you get `NoneType object is not iterable`, you might want to ask your question on **Google** to find how to fix this.

Comment: @user5834454 It's hard to say without seeing your updated code, but consider this: if your `data` doesn't contain `key` in any of its dictionaries...what will `find_deep_value` return? What will the rest of the code do after that? Without seeing the updated code, I would suspect that's part of the problem.

Comment: I updated the code, above with the changes you suggested.