# How to Create Dictionary in Python with Keys

Tags: python, dictionary, output, typeerror

Obviously, this is a question a beginner would ask.  However, I am struggling adding keys to my dictionary to correct the following errors:

```
import csv, json, sys

def find_deep_value(d, key):
# Modified from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568649/convert-json-to-csv-using-python/48569129#48569129

    if key in d:
        return d[key]
    for k in d.keys():
        if isinstance(d[k], dict):
            for j in find_deep_value(d[k], key):
                return j

inputFile = open("pywu.cache.json", 'r')  # open json file
outputFile = open("CurrentObs.csv", 'w')  # load csv file
data = json.load(inputFile)  # load json content
inputFile.close()  # close the input file
output = csv.writer(outputFile)  # create a csv.write

# Gives you latitude coordinates from within the json
lat = find_deep_value(data, "latitude")

# Gives you longitude coordinates from within the json
lon = find_deep_value(data, "longitude")

# Gives you a list of weather from within the json
weather = find_deep_value(data, "weather")

# Gives you a list of temperature_strings from within the json
temp = find_deep_value(data, "temperature_string")

output.writerow([lat, lon, weather, temp])
```

returns the error, below:

```
outputFile.close()
  File "json_to_csv.py", line 20, in <module>
    lat = find_deep_value(data, "latitude")
  File "json_to_csv.py", line 10, in find_deep_value
    for j in find_deep_value(d[k], key):
  File "json_to_csv.py", line 10, in find_deep_value
    for j in find_deep_value(d[k], key):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

How would I go about fixing this?  I've tried creating an empty dictionary "dict={}" and adding that way, but still returns nothing.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: I am a little bit offf topic here but if what you want is to convert a Json to csv, have you considered using pandas library? It has a method which does just that in one line.

Comment: I was able to run the python command, "dict = dict.keys(['latitude', 'longitude', 'weather', 'temp']), which appears to have added the appropriate keys.  However, the script is only returning the first letter/ character of a value.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to handle the case if nothing is found. Therefore, return an empty dict instead of `None`, i.e. having no `return` that is executed:

```
def find_deep_value(d, key):
    if key in d:
        return d[key]
    for k in d.keys():
        if isinstance(d[k], dict):
            for j in find_deep_value(d[k], key):
                return j
    return {}
```