# Extracting specific JSON property into CSV using Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON which is in nested form. I would like to extract billingcode and rate from json and put into csv using pandas python.

```
{
"TransactionId": "1c9cc4b9-a0e1-4228-b382-b244a7674593",
"Number": "1022",
"Version": 534,
"StartDateTime": "2023-04-01 14:12:50.999",
"EndDateTime": "2023-04-01 14:15:32.038",
"LastUpdatedOn": "2023-04-01",
"RateSchedules": [{
        "BillingCodeType": "CPT",
        "BillingCodeTypeVersion": "2023",
        "BillingCode": "0107T",
        "Rates": [{
                "Rate": 14.11,
                "PlaceOfServices": ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "31", "32", "33", "34", "41", "42", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "60", "61", "62", "65", "71", "72", "81", "99"]
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "BillingCodeType": "CPT",
        "BillingCodeTypeVersion": "2023",
        "BillingCode": "0108T",
        "Rates": [{
                "Rate": 14.11,
                "PlaceOfServices": ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "31", "32", "33", "34", "41", "42", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "60", "61", "62", "65", "71", "72", "81", "99"]
            }
        ]
    }
```

}

Above is my JSON and here is my python script. I am running it from Spyder (Python 3.11) from Anaconda that has Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json(r"C:\Users\Jay.Ramachandra\Documents\20230401- 
141250_1022_RI_MC01.json")
df = df.loc[["BillingCode", ["Rate"], "Rates"],"RateSchedules"].T
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\Jay.Ramachandra\Documents\MrfJson.csv")
```

I am referencing this post here to write my python [Convert Json to CSV using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568649/convert-json-to-csv-using-python)

I ran into this and this is now corrected using `r"`

```
runfile('C:/Users/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/.spyder-py3')
  File <unknown>:9
    df = pd.read_json("C:\Users\MC01.json")
                                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

What am i doing wrong? how to correct this?

**Addendum**

I edited my original question to add `r"` in my code and now run into

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Try adding `r` in front of the path `df = pd.read_json(r"C:\Users\MC01.json")` and `df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\MC01Json.csv")`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/how-should-i-write-a-windows-path-in-a-python-string-literal

Comment: @Daviid - I tried it and also \\ but now run into TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 2):

You can use the in-built [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) function to achieve this. The `.json` you have pasted is not formatted correctly as well.

Assuming the JSON file is formatted correctly and saved as `raw.json`, the following code block should give you a Pandas DataFrame

```py
import json
with open('raw.json', 'r') as f:
    d = json.load(f)

# Read the RateSchedules part of the JSON file
d = pd.json_normalize(d['RateSchedules'])

# Extract the first item in the list of Rates
d['Rates'] = d['Rates'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['Rate'])

# Save as CSV
d.to_csv("./MrfJson.csv", index=False)
```

Alternatively, as [JonSG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218663/jonsg) correctly pointed out, you can extend it using `record_path` and `meta`:

```py
import json
with open('raw.json', 'r') as f:
    d = json.load(f)

# Read the RateSchedules part of the JSON file
d = pd.json_normalize(
    d['RateSchedules'],
    record_path=["RateSchedules", "Rates"],
    meta=[["RateSchedules", "BillingCode"]]
)[["RateSchedules.BillingCode", "Rate"]]

# Save as CSV
d.to_csv("./MrfJson.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import pandas as pd
dr = 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\'
dr += 'MC01.json'
with open(dr, 'r') as f:
    jsn = json.load(f)
print(len(jsn['RateSchedules']))

 

df = pd.json_normalize(jsn['RateSchedules'])
rateList = []
for i in df.index:
    for z in df['Rates'][i]:
        rateList.append((jsn['RateSchedules'][i]['BillingCode'],z['Rate']))
pd.DataFrame(rateList, columns=['BillingCode','Rate']).to_csv('C:\\Users\\MrfJson.csv',index=False)
print(len(rateList))
```