# How do I count the occurrence of a given string in list that has more nested lists/dictionaries?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

During a technical phone screen, I was given a list similar to below and asked to count the number of times the string 'a' occurs:

```
input = ['a', 'b', ['a', 'b', {'a': ['b', 'a', [{'b': ['a', 'b', {'a': 'a'}]}]]}]]
```

As you can see, in addition to the 'a' being an item in the list, it can also be an item in nested lists, as well as the keys and/or values in nested dictionaries.

This is the code I have so far in Python:

```
def count_letter_a(arr):

    count = 0

    for item in arr:
        if item == 'a':
            count += 1
        elif isinstance(item, list):
            count_letter_a(item)
        elif isinstance(item, dict):
            for k, v in item.items():
                pass

    return count
```

I'm stuck on what to do with the handling of dictionary keys/values portion of my function. What do I need to do?

Comment: Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807634/find-all-occurrences-of-a-key-in-nested-python-dictionaries-and-lists

Comment: Do you want to count keys and values of dicts?#

Comment: @schwobaseggl, yes keys and values of dicts should count

Answer (score 4):

You can just add the `'a'` count of keys and values, or simple recursively apply it to the items directly. This requires that you count occurrences in `tuples` as well (I included `sets` to complete the built-in collections):

```
def count_a(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, (list, tuple, set)):
        return sum(map(count_a, obj))
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return sum(map(count_a, obj.items()))
    if obj == 'a':
        return 1
    return 0

>>> x = ['a', 'b', ['a', 'b', {'a': ['b', 'a', [{'b': ['a', 'b', {'a': 'a'}]}]]}]]
>>> count_a(x)
7
```

Comment: nice adaptation to include `tuple` and `set`

Comment: Nice answer. I'd rather not use `input` as a variable name though.

Comment: @schwobaseggl, not sure if the use of sum and map would be allowed in an interview setting, especially if the person is not familiar with the python.

Answer (score 3):

You're really close!

```
def count (x):
  if isinstance (x, list):
    return sum (count (y) for y in x)
  elif isinstance (x, dict):
    return sum (count ([ k, v ]) for k,v in x.items ())
  elif x == "a":
    return 1
  else:
    return 0
```

It works like this

```
count ('foo')
# 0

count ([ 'a', 'b', 'c' ])
# 1

count (['a', 'b', ['a', 'b', {'a': ['b', 'a', [{'b': ['a', 'b', {'a': 'a'}]}]]}]])
# 7
```