# Find first occurrence of a key in nested python dictionaries and lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

I saw this question [Find all occurrences of a key in nested python dictionaries and lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807634/find-all-occurrences-of-a-key-in-nested-python-dictionaries-and-lists), but it's return all the values of key.

```
{
  "html": {
    "head": {
      "title": {
        "text": "Your Title Here"
      }
    },
    "body": {
      "bgcolor": "FFFFFF",
      "img": {
        "src": "clouds.jpg",
        "align": "bottom",
        "text": ""
      },
      "a": [
        {
          "href": "http://somegreatsite.com",
          "text": "Link Name"
        },
        {
          "href": "mailto:support@yourcompany.com",
          "text": "support@yourcompany.com"
        }
      ],
      "p": [
        {
          "text": "This is a new paragraph!dasda"
        },
        {
          "h1": {
            "text": "dasda"
          }
        }
        {
          "h3": {
            "text": "hello therereere"
          }
        }
      ],
      "h1": [
        {
          "text": "This is a Header"
        },
        {
          "class": "text-primary",
          "text": "This is a Header"
        }
      ],
      "h2": {
        "text": "This is a Medium Header"
      },
      "b": {
        "text": "This is a new sentence without a paragraph break, in bold italics.",
        "i": {
          "text": "This is a new sentence without a paragraph break, in bold italics."
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to function just find the first occurrence of key

for example:

if i search for `h1`
return:

`{"text": "dasda"}`

Comment: What have you tried in order to accomplish this?

Comment: i tried to edit code of the find all values question, but I couldn't make it right

Comment: sounds like a nice recursive function is your friend

Comment: Please include your attempt in the question and explain what exactly is wrong with it, what it does at the moment and what you'd like it to do.

Comment: Depending on your Python version, it can be hard to guarantee this because dictionaries are generally unordered sequences. Only in more recent versions have their order been guaranteed.

Comment: *insertion* order. Guaranteed since 3.7, impl. dependent from 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be noted your question is constructed a bit weirdly. Technically the first occurrence of `h1` (in regards to hierarchy) is under `html.body.h1`. You seem to want to find the very first occurrence in the dictionary in regards to order, so in other words, you are looking for `html.body.p.h1`. However, a dictionary in Python does not guarantee order for most versions.

Here is a hierarchical solution for the time being:

```py
def func(dictionary: dict, key: str):
    a = None
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if key in dictionary:
            return dictionary[key]
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            a = func(v, key)

    if isinstance(a, list):
        return a[0]
    else:
        return a

print(func(a, "h1"))
```

Outputs:

```py
{'text': 'This is a Header'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this recursively:

```
# Recursively go through dicts and lists to find the given target key
def findKey(target, dic):
    found = False

    # No iteration if it is a string
    if isinstance(dic, str):
        return None

    # Iterate differently if it is a list
    if isinstance(dic, list):
        for elem in dic:
            found = findKey(target, elem)
            if (found):
                return found
        return found

    # Find the key in the dictionary
    for key in dic.keys():
        if (key == target):
            return dic[key]
        else:
            found = findKey(target, dic[key])   
        if (found):
            return found

d = {'html': {'head': {'title': {'text': 'Your Title Here'}}, 'body': {'bgcolor': 'FFFFFF', 'img': {'src': 'clouds.jpg', 'align': 'bottom', 'text': ''}, 'a': [{'href': 'http://somegreatsite.com', 'text': 'Link Name'}, {'href': 'mailto:support@yourcompany.com', 'text': 'support@yourcompany.com'}], 'p': [{'text': 'This is a new paragraph!dasda'}, {'h1': {'text': 'dasda'}}, {'h3': {'text': 'hello therereere'}}], 'h1': [{'text': 'This is a Header'}, {'class': 'text-primary', 'text': 'This is a Header'}], 'h2': {'text': 'This is a Medium Header'}, 'b': {'text': 'This is a new sentence without a paragraph break, in bold italics.', 'i': {'text': 'This is a new sentence without a paragraph break, in bold italics.'}}}}}
findKey("h1", d)
```

Output:

```
{'text': 'dasda'}
```