# Changing all occurrences of a key in nested dictionaries and lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

Let's assume I have a dictionary looks like this, where every instance of `bakery_items` will contain key-value pairs, of which the value is a dictionary itself:

```
{     "bakery_items" : {"pie":{"iscake" : "no", "edible" : "yes"}, "cheesecake":{"iscake" : "yes", "edible" : "yes"}, "shoe":{"iscake" : "no", "edible" : "no"}}
      "key1" : "blah",
      "key2" : "blah blah",
      "nestedlist" : [ 
        { "bakery_items" : {"potato":{"iscake" : "no", "edible" : "yes"}, "pound_cake":{"iscake" : "yes", "edible" : "yes"}, "scale":{"iscake" : "no", "edible" : "no"}},
          "nestednestedlist" : [ 
            { "bakery_items" : {"pomegranate":{"iscake" : "no", "edible" : "yes"}, "sponge_cake":{"iscake" : "yes", "edible" : "yes"}, "sandal":{"iscake" : "no", "edible" : "no"}},
              "keyA" : "blah blah blah" },
            { "bakery_items" : {"pickle":{"iscake" : "no", "edible" : "yes"}, "red_velvet":{"iscake" : "yes", "edible" : "yes"}, "screwdriver":{"iscake" : "no", "edible" : "no"}},
              "keyZ" : "blah blah blah" }],
          "anothernestednestedlist" : [ 
            { "bakery_items" : {"pizza":{"iscake" : "no", "edible" : "yes"}, "fruitcake":{"iscake" : "yes", "edible" : "yes"}, "scissor":{"iscake" : "no", "edible" : "no"}},
              "keyQ" : "blah blah" },
            { "bakery_items" : {"plum":{"iscake" : "no", "edible" : "yes"}, "pancake":{"iscake" : "yno", "edible" : "yes"}, "scratchpad":{"iscake" : "no", "edible" : "no"}},
              "keyW" : "blah" }] } ] }
```

I am able to find the `bakery_items` as a list thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19871956/14743466) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807634), but assume I don't need details about non-cake items (i.e `bakery_items` will only include key-value pairs that have `iscake` as `yes`). The final result should look like this:

```
{     "bakery_items" : {"cheesecake":{"iscake" : "yes", "edible" : "yes"}}
      "key1" : "blah",
      "key2" : "blah blah",
      "nestedlist" : [ 
        { "bakery_items" : {"pound_cake":{"iscake" : "yes", "edible" : "yes"}},
          "nestednestedlist" : [ 
            { "bakery_items" : {"sponge_cake":{"iscake" : "yes", "edible" : "yes"}},
              "keyA" : "blah blah blah" },
            { "bakery_items" : {"red_velvet":{"iscake" : "yes", "edible" : "yes"}},
              "keyZ" : "blah blah blah" }],
          "anothernestednestedlist" : [ 
            { "bakery_items" : {"fruitcake":{"iscake" : "yes", "edible" : "yes"}},
              "keyQ" : "blah blah" },
            { "bakery_items" : {},
              "keyW" : "blah" }] } ] }
```

How can I make sure I find all occurrences `bakery_items` in such a nested structure, and at the same time make it so that I only have items that are cakes?

NOTE: The example is based on the example given by [Matt Swain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/792734) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807634). I am using Python 3.x if it matters.

Comment: So, to confirm: you want to filter the nested dictionary at all levels to only have dictionaries that meet some key constraint for the attributes? And is it OK to assume the nested dictionaries will at least have a `bakery_items` key at every level? And that every item in that will always have a `iscake` key?

Comment: @Grismar I want to filter out the dictionaries under `bakery_items` if they are are not cake (i.e. `iscake` is a `no`). There does not have to be a `bakery_items` at every level. You can assume every `bakery_items` element will have an `iscake` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that:

- every `bakery_items` value has an `iscake` value
- you want to inpect every `list` element in the dictionary to see if there's nested dictionaries in there

Then your code could be (assuming your dictionary is `source`):

```
source = { }  # your dictionary here, with typos like missing commas fixed


def filter_for_cake(d):
    return {
        key: {
            k: v for k, v in value.items() if v['iscake'] == 'yes'
        } if key == 'bakery_items' else
        [
            x if not isinstance(x, dict) else filter_for_cake(x)
            for x in value
        ] if isinstance(value, list) else value
        for key, value in d.items()
    }

print(filter_for_cake(source))
```

Some explanation:

- the function iterates over an entire dictionary
- for each value that has `'bakery_items'` as a key, it assumes it is a dictionary and filters it down to only those elements that have their `'iscake'` set to `'yes'`
- for the other values, if the value is a list, it generates a copy, but passes each dictionary to `filter_for_cake` again (recursion)
- for the remaining values, it just leaves them in as is

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!