# How to debug a recursively called function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, recursion

I am trying to write a function which searches for a key in an arbitrarily deep nested `dict` and returns its value(s) together with the path(s) of ancestor keys -

```
# find_key.py
def find_key(key, targ, path=[]):
    """ Search an aribitarily deep nested dict `targ` for key `key`.
        Return its value(s) together with the path(s) of ancestor keys.
    """
    if key == targ:
        yield v, path
    if isinstance(targ, dict):
        for k, v in targ.items():
            if k == key:
                yield v, path
            else:
                find_key(key, v, path.append(k))
                path.pop()

# test code
targ_1 = {'a': 1, 'b': {'b': 2, 'c': 3}, 'd': {'e': {'f': 4}}}
tests = {'test_a': {'key' : 'a', 'targ': targ_1, 'expect': [(1, [])]},
         'test_b': {'key' : 'b', 'targ': targ_1, 'expect': [({'b': 2, 'c': 3}, []), (2, ['b'])]},
         'test_c': {'key' : 'c', 'targ': targ_1, 'expect': [(3, ['b'])]},
         'test_d': {'key' : 'd', 'targ': targ_1, 'expect': [({'e': {'f': 4}}, [])]},
         'test_e': {'key' : 'e', 'targ': targ_1, 'expect': [({'f': 4}, ['d'])]},
         'test_f': {'key' : 'f', 'targ': targ_1, 'expect': [(4, ['d', 'e'])]}}
for k, v in tests.items():
    if list(find_key(v['key'], v['targ'])) == v['expect']:
        print(k, 'OK')
    else:
        print(k, 'actual:', list(find_key(v['key'], v['targ'])))
        print(k, 'expected:', v['expect'])
```

Executing the code shows that many test cases failed -

```
(3.8) $ python find_key.py 
test_a OK
test_b actual: [({'b': 2, 'c': 3}, [])]
test_b expected: [({'b': 2, 'c': 3}, []), (2, ['b'])]
test_c actual: []
test_c expected: [(3, ['b'])]
test_d OK
test_e actual: []
test_e expected: [({'f': 4}, ['d'])]
test_f actual: []
test_f expected: [(4, ['d', 'e'])]
```

I suspect the problem lies in the recursive call `find_key` so I inserted a `breakpoint()` above the call and re-executed the file -

```
(3.8) $ python find_key.py 
> find_key.py(15)find_key()
-> find_key(key, v, path.append(k))
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> find_key.py(1)find_key()
-> def find_key(key, targ, path=None):
(Pdb) s
GeneratorExit
> find_key.py(1)find_key()
-> def find_key(key, targ, path=None):
(Pdb) s
--Return--
> find_key.py(1)find_key()->None
-> def find_key(key, targ, path=None):
(Pdb) s
> find_key.py(16)find_key()
-> path.pop()
(Pdb)
```

As you can see, Pdb does not step into the recursively called `find_key` but instead issues messages `GeneratorExit` and `--Return--`. How can I debug this issue?

Comment: Have you considered stepping through line by line using an IDE such as VSCode, PyCharm, etc?

Comment: @CoryKramer No, I prefer to learn the basic tools first. Are you suggesting it is not possible with Pdb?

Comment: Debugging likely won't bring you to a satisfactory answer here. The problem is that you create a generator object when calling `find_key(key, v, path.append(k))`, but then you don't do anything with it (e.g. `yield from`). Failing to use a return value isn't something that a debugger is likely to point out.

Comment: The `append` method does not return anything.  So your recursive call passes `None` to `find_key`.

Comment: @Brian I don't have much experience with `yield`, my code was inspired by the top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807634/find-all-occurrences-of-a-key-in-nested-dictionaries-and-lists). Do you recommend I abandon this style for my particular problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**human brain debugging**

```py
# find_key.py
def find_key(key, targ, path=[]):
    """ Search an aribitarily deep nested dict `targ` for key `key`.
        Return its value(s) together with the path(s) of ancestor keys.
    """
    if key == targ:
        yield v, path
    if isinstance(targ, dict):
        for k, v in targ.items():
            if k == key:
                yield v, path
            else:
                find_key(key, v, path.append(k))
                path.pop()
```

```py
targ_1 = {'a': 1, 'b': {'b': 2, 'c': 3}, 'd': {'e': {'f': 4}}}
list(find_key("b", targ_1))
```

Let's simply evaluate the program using our human brain evaluator -

```py
key = "b"
targ = {'a': 1, 'b': {'b': 2, 'c': 3}, 'd': {'e': {'f': 4}}}
path = []
# if key == targ:
#    yield v, path
if isinstance(targ, dict):
    for k, v in targ.items():
        # ("a", 1)
        # ("b", {'b': 2, 'c': 3})
        # ("d", {'e': {'f': 4}})
        k = "a"
        v = 1
        # if k == key:
            # yield v, path
        else:
            find_key(key, v, path.append(k)) # path = ["a"]
            path.pop()                       # path = []
```

In the first iteration of the `for` loop, `k` is not equal to `key` so we run the `else` branch of the program. `find_key` returns a generator, but we don't do anything with it. Ie, no `return` or `yield from` is used. So whatever it does, we can just ignore it entirely as it won't show up in the output of our function. To understand what I mean by that, consider the following example -

```py
def foo():
  1+10      # missing yield or return

foo()
```

```py
None
```

In the program above, `foo` will evaluate `1+10` but nothing happens with it, so it is ignored. This is the same as calling a function like `find_key` without using its return value - python will evaluate it but the result is immediate discarded. Let's move onto the second iteration now -

```py
key = "b"
targ = {'a': 1, 'b': {'b': 2, 'c': 3}, 'd': {'e': {'f': 4}}}
path = []
# if key == targ:
#    yield v, path
if isinstance(targ, dict):
    for k, v in targ.items():
        # ("a", 1)
        # ("b", {'b': 2, 'c': 3})
        # ("d", {'e': {'f': 4}})
        k = "b"
        v = {'b': 2, 'c': 3}
        if k == key:
            yield v, path            # ({'b': 2, 'c': 3}, [])
        # else:
            # find_key(key, v, path.append(k)) # path = ["a"]
            # path.pop()                       # path = []
```

Above, we see the second iteration of the `for` loop. Here `k == key`, so now we `yield`. Note because you use the `else` keyword, we won't recur `find_key`. That means there is no attempt to find additional `key = "b"` values in `v`.

```py
key = "b"
targ = {'a': 1, 'b': {'b': 2, 'c': 3}, 'd': {'e': {'f': 4}}}
path = []
# if key == targ:
#    yield v, path
if isinstance(targ, dict):
    for k, v in targ.items():
        # ("a", 1)
        # ("b", {'b': 2, 'c': 3})
        # ("d", {'e': {'f': 4}})
        k = "d"
        v = {'e': {'f': 4}}
        # if k == key:
            # yield v, path
        else:
            find_key(key, v, path.append(k)) # path = ["d"]
            path.pop()                       # path = []
```

In the third iteration of the `for` loop, it is just the same as the first. `k` is not equal to `key` and so `find_key` is called and the result is ignored.

The output is simple to determine. The second iteration where `k == "b"` is the only output from our function. Since you wrap the `find_key` call in `list(...)` this is the only result we will see in the list -

```py
[({'b': 2, 'c': 3}, [])]
```

**fixing the problem**

Here are the things I noticed -

1. You are missing `yield from` before the recursive call to `find_key`.
2. The conditional logic can be simplified
3. Using `else` prevents recursion on values, `v`, where `k == key`
4. Avoiding mutation `.append` and `.pop` makes reasoning about the algorithm easier

```py
def find_key(key, targ, path = []):
  """ Search an aribitarily deep nested dict `targ` for key `key`.
      Return its value(s) together with the path(s) of ancestor keys.
  """
  if isinstance(targ, dict):
    for (k,v) in targ.items():
      if k == key:
        yield (v, path)
      yield from find_key(key, v, [*path, k])  # <- no else, yield from
```

```py
test_a OK
test_b OK
test_c OK
test_d OK
test_e OK
test_f OK
```

**path param**

You have the option to remove the `path` parameter from `find_key` signature as well -

```py
# find_key.py
def find_key(key, targ):                  # <- no path arg
  """ Search an aribitarily deep nested dict `targ` for key `key`.
      Return its value(s) together with the path(s) of ancestor keys.
  """
  if isinstance(targ, dict):
    for (k,v) in targ.items():
      if k == key:
        yield (v, [])                     # <- empty path
      for (v, path) in find_key(key, v):  # <- get path from recursive result
        yield (v, [k, *path])             # <- prepend path
```

**direct ancestor**

Finally I think it's odd that the direct ancestor doesn't appear in the result. Ie,

```py
list(find_key("a", {"a":1}))
```

```py
[(1, [])]
```

According to the result above, the path to `1` is empty, `[]`. I would expect the result to be `[(1, ["a"])]`. Ie, *the path to `1` is `targ["a"]`*. This is an easy change -

```py
# find_key.py
def find_key(key, targ):
  """ Search an aribitarily deep nested dict `targ` for key `key`.
      Return its value(s) together with the path(s) of ancestor keys.
  """
  if isinstance(targ, dict):
    for (k,v) in targ.items():
      if k == key:
        yield (v, [k])                    # <- base path
      for (v, path) in find_key(key, v):
        yield (v, [k, *path])
```

```py
list(find_key("b", targ_1))
```

*The path to `{'b': 2, 'c': 3}` is `targ["b"]`*
*The path to `2` is `targ["b"]["b"]`*

```py
[({'b': 2, 'c': 3}, ['b']), (2, ['b', 'b'])]
```

Comment: Apparently the answer is 'no' (with a software debugger) but your response was extremely informative - thanks! Since Python represents the widely used JSON data format in similar nested compound structures via [json.load(s)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) functions, I was surprised that I could not find a widely used / debugged module which provides out of the box functionality for these kind of requirements. Is it normal for Python developers to hand code such solutions?

Comment: @user2309803 ha I didn't mean to imply the answer is _no_. But maybe I meant to imply that homing in on your precise issue with a debugger is sometimes more trouble than it's worth. The issue here is nothing happens with the recursive call to `find_key` but it gets run anyway and the debugger will still hit your breakpoints so it _looks_ like things are working properly. A careful read of the program with our human interpreter can detect certain issues that are hard to detect with a debugger.

Comment: The issue is compounded by the fact that python is a multi-paradigm language. It's perfectly valid to call functions and ignore the return values. You might be able to catch it with a linter, but idk I don't use linters. Other languages might issue a warning for such a thing or use implicit returns. I've always wanted to write a stack visualizer for python programs, and I think it's possible, but it would involve writing an interpreter that is capable of understanding all valid python programs - not a small task.