# Python: Replace nested dict key's value in entire json whether inside a list or directly a dict

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to replace the values inside a json for dictionary's key it could be present as dictionay directly in json or as a dictionary inside another list as below:

```
{ 
  "appType": "popper",
  "createdAt": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "people": [{
            "name": "Vol1",
            "label": "Vol1",
            "peopleInfo": [{
                "name": "ram",
                "age": "2407653459860",
                "id": "1b738651-da9f-4c85-88c1-70dbfe1976681"
            }],
            "itemInfo": {
                "id": "ee763970-51e2-57a5-955c-d72fc3e28a3f",
                "name": "xyz",
                "type": "any",
                "managed": False
            }
        }],
  "itemInfo": [{
            "managed": False,
            "vendorName": "any",
            "serialNumber": "AF-10124"
             }],
}
```

Desired Output:

```
{ 
  "appType": "popper",
  "createdAt": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "peopleInfo": [{
            "name": "Vol1",
            "label": "Vol1",
            "people": [{
                "name": "ram",
                "age": "2407653459860",
                "id": "1b738651-da9f-4c85-88c1-70dbfe1976681"
            }],
            "itemInfo": {
                "id": "ee763970-51e2-57a5-955c-d72fc3e28a3f",
                "name": "xyz",
                "type": "any",
                "managed": True
            }
        }],
  "itemInfo": [{
            "managed": True,
            "vendorName": "any",
            "serialNumber": "AF-10124"
             }],
}
```

so as in desired output i want to update/replace the **managed** flag as *True* from *false* for **itemInfo** directly in json and as well as **itemInfo** in **peopleInfo** List using python. The iteminfo dictionary can be present in entire json in some different list as well. Thankyou for the help.

I have written below code but not able to make it a general one:

`i["details"]["storageSystemsInfo"][0]["managed"] = True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 2:

Change only "managed" fields within "itemInfo" dictionary like you asked.
(This is not pretty or clean code)

```
# Python 3
def change_this_key_to_true(key, var):
    if hasattr(var,'items'):
        for k, v in var.items(): 
            if k == key:
                var[k] = True
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                change_this_key_to_true(key, v)
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                for d in v:
                    change_this_key_to_true(key, d)
    else:
        if isinstance(var, list):
            for element in var:
                change_this_key_to_true(key, element)


all_item_info_dics = []
def get_all_values_with_key(key, var):
    if hasattr(var, 'items'):
        for k, v in var.items(): 
            if k == key:
                all_item_info_dics.append(var[k])
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                get_all_values_with_key(key, v)
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                for d in v:
                    get_all_values_with_key(key, d)

get_all_values_with_key("itemInfo", myJson)
print(all_item_info_dics)
print("\n")
change_this_key_to_true("managed", all_item_info_dics)
print(myJson)
```

Update:
(That's my first answer, took me a while, hope it's good :) )

```
# Python 3
def change_this_key_to_true(key, var):
    if hasattr(var,'items'):
        for k, v in var.items():
            if k == key:
                var[k] = True
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                change_this_key_to_true(key, v)
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                for d in v:
                    change_this_key_to_true(key, d)

change_this_key_to_true("managed", myJson)
print(myJson)
```

Go through all the fields in a complex dict/list/"weird combination of the two" and looking for a field named "managed" and change it to True.
Based my answer on this:
[Find all occurrences of a key in nested dictionaries and lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807634/find-all-occurrences-of-a-key-in-nested-dictionaries-and-lists)

Original answer:

```
x["people"][0]["itemInfo"]["managed"] = True
x["itemInfo"][0]["managed"] = True
```

Comment: If it helps, please upvote and mark my answer

Comment: This is fine and thanks for your help, but i am looking for a general solution where iteminfo can be present anywhere in json and not in a fixed key, so basically peopleInfo key can be different in the json.

Comment: The updated answer is good, thanks , but i need managed flag for only itemInfo dictionary not all managed flags need to be updated. just the one for itemInfo dict/list however it is. and again the name iteminfo can be any other name as well :)