# Searching for certain values in asn1 cert

Tags: python-3.x, x509, asn1crypto

The `asn1crypto` package with x509 is being used. I'd like to find particular values in the .der file. The file is opened and read(), then:

```
mycert = x509.Certificate.load(data)
```

This returns an object of type `asn1crypto.x509.Certificate` like so `b'0\x81\x50\...'`. In debug, `mycert` can be expanded to show the various keys and values, however I'd like to search directly in the 'mycert' for such keys/values. How can I do this?

EDIT:

The asn1crypto package doesn't have to be used, another one can be used instead.

EDIT:

Expanded code:

```
with open(cert_path, 'rb') as cert_file:
    data = cert_file.read()

mycert = x509.Certificate.load(data)

a = mycert.native # doesn't work!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `asn1crypto.x509` the attribute `native` contains the native Python datatype representation of the certificate. The values are hierarchically structured and can be OrderedDicts as well:

```
import asn1crypto.x509 as x509
import pprint

with open('crt.der', mode='rb') as file:
    data = file.read()

    mycert = x509.Certificate.load(data)

    pprint.pprint(mycert.native)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('tbs_certificate',
              OrderedDict([('version', 'v3'),
                           ('serial_number', 15158908894724103801),
                           ('signature',
                            OrderedDict([('algorithm', 'sha256_rsa'),
                                         ('parameters', None)])),
                           ('issuer',
                            OrderedDict([('country_name', 'XX'),
                                         ('state_or_province_name',
                                          'Some-State'),
                                         ('locality_name', 'Some-City'),
                                         ('organization_name', 'example ltd'),
                                         ('common_name', 'www.example.com'),
                                         ('email_address',
                                          'info@example.com')])),
                           ('validity',
                            OrderedDict([('not_before',
                                          datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 5, 6, 58, 21, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)),
                                         ('not_after',
                                          datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 5, 6, 58, 21, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc))])),
                           ('subject',
                            OrderedDict([('country_name', 'XX'),
                                         ('state_or_province_name',
                                          'Some-State'),
                                         ('locality_name', 'Some-City'),
                                         ('organization_name', 'example ltd'),
                                         ('common_name', 'www.example.com'),
                                         ('email_address',
                                          'info@example.com')])),
...
```

You can find several discussions in SO on how to search in a nested dict like "[Find all occurrences of a key in nested dictionaries and lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9807634/18667225)".

Comment: thank you for the tip. In my case I get a python-BaseException (KeyError: '1.3.5.....') when trying to call the mycert.native

Comment: @pymat, I have added the full reproducible example to my answer. Two points: (1) Could you please check if this standalone is working with your der-file? (2) Can you please explain, how you are trying to "call" `mycert.native`? It would be best if you would add reproducible code and full error message to your question.

Comment: using your example, I noticed that when I use "test0 = mycert[0]" I get the TbsCertificate. Then when debugging I get a similar structure like you in the ppring example above, when I exapand the 'native' attribute. However when I use 'native' on 'test0', I get the key error.

Comment: @pymat, what could be the difference between your and my environment? I'm using `asn1crypto 1.5.1`. What are you using?