# How can I embed a dictionary into another dictionary?(Python)

Tags: dictionary

I've got a problem in a small programming exercise, in which I should create a mutable 'phone book' from a dictionary embedded into another. One problem with the exercise is that I have to create a structure with several dicts, like this:
{Name: Smith
 first name: Michael
 Phone Number: 2345

Name: Miller
 first name: Tom}

While I can search for the Name Part and thus add something to the entry for Miller.

I understand that I can embed dicts as a value to a key with

```
    dict1['dict2']
```

but this doesn't seem to work how it should. Can you give me an example how I can write this?

Comment: It sounds like you need to decide what the key on the outer dict will be, i.e. how do you want to look up the info for `Tom Miller`?

Comment: Refer to this answer it should clear somethings up for you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16333441/2062443

Comment: @theorifice The Problem is that there seems to be a Key and a value before the inner dict starts