# Sending a nested dictionary into ironpython from Unity

Tags: python, dictionary, unity-game-engine, nested, ironpython

I'm trying to send a nested dictionary from unity c# into ironpython. The Dictionary looks like this

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>> results;
```

I am running the python process after setting the variable in my .py script.
I know the syntax to convert c# into python for a dictionary

```
my_dictionary = dict(MyDictFromUnity)
```

But i can't seem to figure out the syntax for converting a nested dictionary
I tried this

```
my_dictionary = dict(dict(MyDictFromUnity))
```

I didn't have high hopes for that working but was worth a shot.

Does anyone have any idea what the syntax for this might be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create nested dict in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333296/how-do-you-create-nested-dict-in-python)