# Python: How to add a list to a named multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, dictionary

In PHP you can easily create and populate multidimensional arrays like this:

```
$points = array();
$points["Landmarks"]["Latitude"] = $some_array_containing_lat_values;
$points["Landmarks"]["Longitude"] = $some_array_containing_lon_values;
```

What's the pythonic way of doing this?

I already tried lists, dictionaries and numpy arrays, but neither was working. Using unnamed (numbered) arrays is not an option, since they are created from external files with inconsistent structure and naming, so the data must be retrieved from the array by name, not by index.

Sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I've been searching for an entire day to no avail and I'm desperately running out of time.

Comment: I don't see why dictionary wouldn't work? Just need to initiate different levels separately: `points = {}`, `points['Landmarks'] = {}`, `points['Landmarks']['Latitude'] = lat_array`, etc.

Comment: Or `points = {'Landmarks': {'Latitude': lat_array}}`

Comment: If you want to skip the `points['Landmarks'] = {}`, you could use a defaultdict -- `points = defaultdict(dict)`,`points['Landmarks']['Latitude'] = lat_array` -- instead

Comment: A quick glance at the PHP docs suggests that `array` combines in a sense the functionality of Python `dictionary` and `list`.  In Python those are not inherently multidimensional, but either can contain a dictionary or list as values, producing a kind of multidimensionality.  You may need to show some of you Python trials and explain what the problem is with each.  So far the problem description is too generic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you want to retrieve an item from a data structure using a string as a keyword (e.g. "Landmarks"), a dictionary is what you're looking for.

To have the "multidimensional" functionality of `points["Landmarks"]["Latitude"]`, you will have to have a dictionary inside another dictionary:

```
points = {'Landmarks': {'Latitude': lat_array, 'Longitude': lon_array}}
```

You can also use a `deafaultdict`, which supports nested dictionaries:

```
from collections import deafaultdict
points = defaultdict(dict)
points["Landmarks"]["Latitude"] = lat_array
points["Landmarks"]["Longitude"] = lon_array
```

You can see more about nested dictionaries [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333296/how-do-you-create-nested-dict-in-python).

Comment: Thanks a lot, defaultdict does the trick! Initiating the levels seperately works too.