# python dicts of dicts out of python dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have predefined dictionaries and I need a function to form one dictionary out of several input dicts where the keys are the names of the input dictionaries.

For example, I have the following:

```
double_left = {
    'left': 6
}

double_right = {
    'right': 6
}
```

The output should be:

```
>>> output_dicts
{'double_left': {'left': 6}, 'double_right': {'right': 6}}
```

I already tried:
[How do you create nested dict in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333296/how-do-you-create-nested-dict-in-python)
but could not derive the answer.

Suggestions ?

Comment: Please show what you mean by "tried".

Comment: Your question is unclear. How would you choose which dicts to include in your final one? If you want to start with a list of their names, you'd better create a dict in the first place in order to structure your data, rather than having similar but unrelated variables.

Comment: You can do literally: `{'double_left': double_left, 'double_right': double_right}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it dynamically without hardcoding the names of the top-level items, you can get a list of variables by names using `globals()` and/or `locals()`. For example:

```
output = {}
for name, val in globals().items():
    # Skipping variables that aren't dicts, and special
    # variables starting with '_'
    if isinstance(val, dict) and not name.startswith('_'):
        output[name] = val

for name, val in locals().items():
    if isinstance(val, dict) and not name.startswith('_'):
        output[name] = val
```

Or more compact:

```
output = {name:val for name, val in (list(locals().items()) +
                                     list(globals().items()))
          if isinstance(val, dict) and not name.startswith('_')}
```

Comment: awesome! it is a function then .. that gets the items from its environment with locals().items()

Comment: @criticalth there's probably no good reason for you to do this.

Comment: poor integration with inhouse software ... :D

Answer (score 2):

Just make a new dictionary.

```
output_dict = {"double_left": double_left, "double_right": double_right}
print(output_dict)
```

Comment: Can you make that a function that takes only the dictionaries as inputs ? how can you make the dictionary name a string ?

Comment: @criticalth, you can't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string

Answer (score 0):

Just like your current dicts have 'key': 'value' pairs, with your values being ints (6), you can create a new dict with the keys being the name of the dict and the values being the nested dict.

```
output_dicts = {'double_left': double_left, 'double_right': double_right}

>>> output_dicts
{'double_left': {'left': 6}, 'double_right': {'right': 6}}
```

You can also use `dict_name[new_key] = new_value`.
For example:

```
output_dicts['double_left'] = double_left
output_dicts['double_right'] = double_right
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Newdict = dict(double_left = { 'left': 6},double_right = 
{'right': 6})
```