# How to declare a nested dictionary in Python?

Tags: python

I want to declare a nested dictionary, with the key value pairs being a string and dict, with this nested dict having a key value pair of string and int). How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: `defaultdict(dict)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you create nested dict in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333296/how-do-you-create-nested-dict-in-python)

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 2):

The same way as you make a regular dictionary, except put it inside another dictionary.

```
outer_dict = {
  "inner1": {
    "keyA": 1,
    "keyB": 2,
    "keyC": 3,
  },
  "inner2": {
    "keyD": 4,
    "keyE": 5,
    "keyF": 6,
    "keyG": 7,
  },
}
```

If you wanted to annotate this with type hinting, you would do essentially the same thing, putting a `Dict` inside another `Dict`:

```
outer_dict: Dict[str, Dict[str, int]] = { ... }
```

Comment: @mohammedwazeem The outer one is a dict. It has two keys: `"inner1"` and `"inner2"`. A set *would* also use curly brackets, but a set doesn't have keys (so, `{1, 2, 3}` would be a set, but `{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}` would be a dict). If you try copypasting this code into a python console and to `type(outer_dict)`, it says `<class 'dict'>`.

Comment: hi thanks for the help, if I don't have any data to put in yet and just want to declare it i use the type hinting as you suggested? thanks!

Comment: @mm21 If you're just declaring it then yes, that's how you would use type hinting.

Comment: sorry i am still confused, would I not do outer_dict = Dict[str, Dict[str, int]]

Comment: @mm21 What do you mean by _declare it_ ?

Comment: sorry i mean to say initialize it, in C++ you would say map<string,map<string,int> outerdict , so I am trying to do this in python

Comment: @mm21 As type hinting always goes, you can just declare a variable by doing `variablename: Type`, without assigning it to anything explicitly. Though it's probably a good idea to at least set it to whatever the "zero" or "empty" type.