# Try to get hierarchical string structure into dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm pretty new to python and now for 2 days, I'm struggling with getting a hierarchical based string structure into a python dict/list structure to handle it better:

Example Strings:

```
Operating_System/Linux/Apache
Operating_System/Linux/Nginx
Operating_System/Windows/Docker
Operating_System/FreeBSD/Nginx
```

What I try to achieve is to split each string up and pack it into a python dict, that should be
something like:

```
{'Operating_System': [{'Linux': ['Apache', 'Nginx']}, {'Windows': ['Docker']}, {'FreeBSD': ['Nginx']}]}
```

I tried multiple ways, including zip() and some ways by string split('/') and then doing
it by nested iteration but I could not yet solve it. Does anyone know a good/elegant way to achieve
something like this with python3 ?

best regards,

Chris

Comment: are they individual strings or lumped into a single string?

Comment: Are the number of delimiters fixed at 2 or can there be greater nesting in the resulting dictionaries than there is in your example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way about it ... [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) could help here :

```
#assumption is that it is a collection of strings
strings = ["Operating_System/Linux/Apache",
"Operating_System/Linux/Nginx",
"Operating_System/Windows/Docker",
"Operating_System/FreeBSD/Nginx"]

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(dict)
e = defaultdict(list)
m = [entry.split('/') for entry in strings]

print(m)

[['Operating_System', 'Linux', 'Apache'],
 ['Operating_System', 'Linux', 'Nginx'],
 ['Operating_System', 'Windows', 'Docker'],
 ['Operating_System', 'FreeBSD', 'Nginx']]

for a,b,c in m:
    e[b].append(c)
    d[a] = e

print(d)

defaultdict(dict,
            {'Operating_System': defaultdict(list,
                         {'Linux': ['Apache', 'Nginx'],
                          'Windows': ['Docker'],
                          'FreeBSD': ['Nginx']})})
```

if u want them exactly as u shared in ur output, u could skip the `defaultdict(dict)` part :

```
mapp = {'Operating_System':[{k:v} for k,v in e.items()]}
mapp

{'Operating_System': [{'Linux': ['Apache', 'Nginx']},
  {'Windows': ['Docker']},
  {'FreeBSD': ['Nginx']}]
```

}

this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16333441/7175713) was also useful

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. I didn't know defaultdict and that is very helpful