# Is it possible to make a nested dictionary out of like a Chained Dictionary and a List?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

```
students = ["Terri", "Gerald", "Sam"]
classes = {'Math': '98', 'Science': '80', 'Literature': '75'}
```

now I want to be able to know the grade that Terri got in his math class and I want the answer to be `98`, `dict['Terri']['Math'] = 98`.

How would I do that?  Is there a way around this where I can convert this to other types of collections?  TY

I would like the nested dictionary to read like:

```
{Terri: Math:98, Science: 80....} # and so on....
```

Comment: You can certinly do it. Try `{'Terri':{'Math':98,'Physics':90}, 'Gerald':{'Math':98,'Physics':85}}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you create nested dict in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333296/how-do-you-create-nested-dict-in-python)