# Converting the dictionary inside the list to the nested dictionary

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, list, uitableview

have a list of tuples, called employee_data, where each list element is a tuple that corresponds to a class and a point that a employee can earn. For example,

```
employee_data = 
[{
   "name": "asd",
   "lastname": "abc",
   "birthday": 15/15/2021,
   "birthplace": "CA",
   "live_place": "USA",
   "email": "sss.com",
   "website": "sss.com",
   "Phone_number": "12345678901",
   "work_number": "abc",
   "save_date": 15/15/2021,
   "start_date": 15/15/2021,
   "leave_date": 15/15/2021,
   "project": "End-Of-Support",
   "age_in_months": 256 ,
   "Age_in_Years": 15.3,
   "Computer_name": 'pc1',
   "computer_cpu": 8,
   "computer_ram": 12,
   "computer_ssd": 256,
 },
 {
   "name": "asd",
   "lastname": "abc",
   "birthday": 16/15/2021,
   "birthplace": "CA",
   "live_place": "USA",
   "email": "sss.com",
   "website": "sss.com",
   "Phone_number": "12345678901",
   "work_number": "abc",
   "save_date": 15/15/2021,
   "start_date": 15/15/2021,
   "leave_date": 15/15/2021,
   "project": "End-Of-Support",
   "age_in_months": 256 ,
   "Age_in_Years": 15.3,
   "Computer_name": 'pc1',
   "computer_cpu": 8,
   "computer_ram": 12,
   "computer_ssd": 256,
 }]
```

| Nested Dict ID | name | lastname | birthday | birthplace | live_place | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | asd | abc | 15/15/2021 | USA | CAD | asd@mail.com |
| 1 | asd2 | abc | 16/15/2021 | CAD | USA | abc@mail.com |

I tried this functions but couldn't fix error.
Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333296/how-do-you-create-nested-dict-in-python)!

My issue is, this dictionary in list. I want to create nested dict for mapping datas.

```
[{0{"name": "asd",
   "lastname": "abc",
   "birthday": 15/15/2021,
   "birthplace": "CA",
   "live_place": "USA",
   "email": "sss.com",}
1{"name": "asd2",
   "lastname": "abc",
   "birthday": 16/15/2021,
   "birthplace": "CA",
   "live_place": "USA",
   "email": "sss.com",}]
```

if employee has same last name i want to get employee nestedDictID than i'll import all infomartion on different list and table ..

```
d = { x['lastname']: x['abc'] for x in employee_data}
KeyError: 'abc'
```

Comment: Hello, so what is your question?

Comment: That's not a list of tuples.  That's a list of dictionaries.

Comment: please show what you tried and explain how it doesn't work with lots of data?  also, the question title asks about printing data, but the body mentions importing to sql; focus on just one of those

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list of tuples with the required data extracted from json which you can use to export it to SQL tables. Refer the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [(item.get('name'), item.get('lastname'),item.get('birthday'),item.get('birthplace'), item.get('live_place'), item.get('email')) for item in employee_data]
print(data)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=['name', 'lastname', 'birthday','birthplace','live_place','email']))
```

And then you can use `df.to_sql` from pandas.

Comment: That's what i look for. Thank You.

Comment: @sapkernel cool. If this is your solution you were looking for then can you upvote and mark this as answer to your question :-)