# How to make a dictionary to a nested dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary as follow:

```
d1 = {1:"Peter", 2:"Teddy"}
```

I want to make it to:

```
d1 = {1:"Peter", 2:"Teddy", 3:{"Oliver" : "Big"}}
```

I have tried but it doesn't work:

```
d1[3]["Oliver"]="Big"
```

Comment: Precede with `d1[3] = {}`

Comment: or `d1[3] = {"Oliver" : "Big"}`

Comment: if the key `1` may or may not exist with a dictionary already, and you don't want to overwrite it, but add another key to the existing dictionary already there, then use: `d1.setdefault(3, {})['Oliver'] = 'big'`

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333296/how-do-you-create-nested-dict-in-python
There is also lots of information about nested dictionaries online.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
d1[3] = {"Oliver": "Big"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first try

```py
d1[3] = {}
```

Then

```py
d1[3]["Oliver"]="Big"
```