# Searching for keys in a nested dictionary

Tags: python

I have a JSON object in Python represented as a nested lists of dictionaries. (Some of the values of the dictionary are dictionaries themselves, and so on.)

I want to be able to search for a key on all branches of this nested dictionary structure.
When I find the key I want to be able to return the full key path that leads to it.

For example:  I'm looking for "special agents" who have a "special address key", but not all special agents have it, and those that do have it in inconsistent paths in their JSON.

So I search for key `Special Address code`.
The result should return:

```
/'People'/'SpecialAgents'/'007'/'Special Address code'/
```

So I will be able to reach its information in that way:

```
json_obj['People']['SpecialAgents']['007']['Special Address code']
```

Note that this is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807634/find-all-occurences-of-a-key-in-nested-python-dictionaries-and-lists) but I need the full path to each instance of the key found.

Comment: Sounds like you need a JSON equivalent of XPath. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481380/is-there-a-json-equivalent-of-xquery-xpath) has a few examples.

Comment: what if there are multiple keys that are the same?

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681301/search-for-a-key-in-a-nested-python-dictionary https://stackoverflow.com/a/16508328/42223

Answer (score 13):

You need a recursive search.

You can define a function to deeply search in your input json:

```
def find_in_obj(obj, condition, path=None):

    if path is None:
        path = []    

    # In case this is a list
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for index, value in enumerate(obj):
            new_path = list(path)
            new_path.append(index)
            for result in find_in_obj(value, condition, path=new_path):
                yield result 

    # In case this is a dictionary
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key, value in obj.items():
            new_path = list(path)
            new_path.append(key)
            for result in find_in_obj(value, condition, path=new_path):
                yield result 

            if condition == key:
                new_path = list(path)
                new_path.append(key)
                yield new_path
```

We can then use the example JSON in this [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807634/find-all-occurences-of-a-key-in-nested-python-dictionaries-and-lists) to test the recursive search:

```
In [15]: my_json = { "id" : "abcde",
   ....:   "key1" : "blah",
   ....:   "key2" : "blah blah",
   ....:   "nestedlist" : [ 
   ....:     { "id" : "qwerty",
   ....:       "nestednestedlist" : [ 
   ....:         { "id" : "xyz",
   ....:           "keyA" : "blah blah blah" },
   ....:         { "id" : "fghi",
   ....:           "keyZ" : "blah blah blah" }],
   ....:       "anothernestednestedlist" : [ 
   ....:         { "id" : "asdf",
   ....:           "keyQ" : "blah blah" },
   ....:         { "id" : "yuiop",
   ....:           "keyW" : "blah" }] } ] }
```

Let's find every instance of the key 'id' and return the full path that gets us there:

```
In [16]: for item in find_in_obj(my_json, 'id'):
   ....:     print item
   ....:     
['nestedlist', 0, 'nestednestedlist', 0, 'id']
['nestedlist', 0, 'nestednestedlist', 1, 'id']
['nestedlist', 0, 'id']
['nestedlist', 0, 'anothernestednestedlist', 0, 'id']
['nestedlist', 0, 'anothernestednestedlist', 1, 'id']
['id']
```

Comment: +1 This works. Nice. I tested it searching for `id` in the object from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807634/find-all-occurences-of-a-key-in-nested-python-dictionaries-and-lists). Any comments on how it works, and where you got it from? (Did you write all this code from scratch?)

Comment: @LondonRob this function iterates keys and stores a state of the current path. it's based on yield return (which simplifies the solution). wrote it from scratch followed by OP description

Comment: Mind if I edit this a bit to show a more complete example? It shows your work off better than your single result does currently.

Comment: @LondonRob feel free to improve this answer (and any other one on this site :P )

Answer (score 3):

You need to search a tree. Here's the easiest way to do it.

It could be enhanced - for example, it is better to use None as default arg value instead of some object. Also, this is depth first search - you may want to get only one result, and that's when width first search is better (read about both those terms on wikipedia if you don't know them).

```
import json

example_json = """{
 "someList" : [
  {
   "x": {
    "y": {
     "z": "Some value"
    }
   }
  }, 
  {
   "x": {
    "y": {
     "a": "Wrong key"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
"""

struct = json.loads(example_json)

def find_all_with_key(wanted_key, tree, path=tuple()):
    if isinstance(tree, list):
        for idx, el in enumerate(tree):
            yield from find_all_with_key(wanted_key, el, path+(idx,))
    elif isinstance(tree, dict):
        for k in tree:
            if k == wanted_key:
                yield path +(k, )
        # you can add order of width-search by sorting result of tree.items()
        for k, v in tree.items(): 
            yield from find_all_with_key(wanted_key, v, path+(k,))

def retrieve(tree, path):
    for p in path:
        tree = tree[p]
    return tree

result = list(find_all_with_key("z", struct))
expected = [ ("someList", 0, "x", "y", "z") ]

assert result == expected
assert retrieve(struct, result[0]) == "Some value"
```

Comment: this is python3 only syntax, you also don't need to call .keys to iterate over the dict keys

Comment: Told ya, this could use some enhancements :P Another ugly thing is usage of isinstance(), but that's not the point. Also, I think that "python3 only" isn't a bad thing - I'm a strong supporter of migrating to new line instead of using p2.7.

Comment: Well until pythons fairy godmother comes along and clicks her fingers to make all python code ever written python 3 compatible I guess python2 code will still have to be written. I don't see anything wrong with `isinstance()` at all that is necessary unlike keys ;)

Comment: Fixed. Anyway, only difference is that in p2 you should use for x in X: yield x instead of yield from X. More on it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17581397/1219585 if anyone would be looking