# Python: Updating a value in a deeply nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am importing and manipulating some deeply nested JSON (imported as a dictionary).  It can assign the values just fine using code like:

```
query['query']['function_score']['query']['multi_match']['operator'] = 'or'
query['query']['function_score']['query']['multi_match'].update({
        'minimum_should_match' : '80%' })
```

But it's ugly and cumbersome as nuts.  I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to assign values to deep-nested keys that's reasonably efficient?

I've read about possibly using an in-memory SQLlite db, but the data is going back into json after a bit of manipulation.

Comment: You can assign one of the inners dictionaries to variable and manipulate it: `d = query[1][2][3][4]; d[5].update(..)`

Comment: Don't use such deeply nested dictionariess.

Comment: @Natecat: why not? what is the alternative? If you do have a lengthy configuration to do, why not?

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681301/search-for-a-key-in-a-nested-python-dictionary https://stackoverflow.com/a/16508328/42223

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
multi_match = query['query']['function_score']['query']['multi_match']
multi_match['operator'] = 'or'
multi_match.update({'minimum_should_match' : '80%' })
```

Answer (score 3):

JSONPath (via 'jsonpath_rw') makes it less cumbersome:

Previous:

```
>>> query
{u'query': {u'function_score': {u'query': {u'multi_match': {u'min_should_match': u'20%'}}}}}
```

Update:

```
>>> found = jsonpath_rw.parse("$..multi_match").find(query)[0]
>>> found.value["operator"] == "or"
>>> found.value["min_should_match"] = "80%"`
```

Afterwards:

```
>>> query
{u'query': {u'function_score': {u'query': {u'multi_match': {'min_should_match': '80%', u'operator': u'or'}}}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

The chosen answer is definitely the way to go.  The problem I (later) found is that my nested key can appear at an varying levels.  So I needed to be able to traverse the dict and find the path to the node first, and THEN do the update or addition.

jsonpath_rw was the immediate solution, but I got some strange results trying to use it.  I gave up after a couple hours of wrestling with it.

At the risk of getting shot down for being a clunky newb, I did end up fleshing out a few functions (based on other code I found on SO) that natively do some nice things to address my needs:

```
def find_in_obj(obj, condition, path=None):
    ''' generator finds full path to nested dict key when key is at an unknown level 
        borrowed from http://stackoverflow.com/a/31625583/5456148'''
    if path is None:
        path = []

    # In case this is a list
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for index, value in enumerate(obj):
            new_path = list(path)
            new_path.append(index)
            for result in find_in_obj(value, condition, path=new_path):
                yield result

    # In case this is a dictionary
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key, value in obj.items():
            new_path = list(path)
            new_path.append(key)
            for result in find_in_obj(value, condition, path=new_path):
                yield result

            if condition == key:
                new_path = list(path)
                new_path.append(key)
                yield new_path


def set_nested_value(nested_dict, path_list, key, value):
    ''' add or update a value in a nested dict using passed list as path
        borrowed from http://stackoverflow.com/a/11918901/5456148'''
    cur = nested_dict
    path_list.append(key)
    for path_item in path_list[:-1]:
        try:
            cur = cur[path_item]
        except KeyError:
            cur = cur[path_item] = {}

    cur[path_list[-1]] = value
    return nested_dict


def update_nested_dict(nested_dict, findkey, updatekey, updateval):
    ''' finds and updates values in nested dicts with find_in_dict(), set_nested_value()'''
    return set_nested_value(
        nested_dict,
        list(find_in_obj(nested_dict, findkey))[0],
        updatekey,
        updateval
    )
```

**find_in_obj()** is a generator that finds a path to a given nested key.

**set_nested_values()** will either *update* key/value in dict with given list or *add* it if it doesn't exist.

**update_nested_dict()** is a "wrapper" for the two functions that takes in the nested dict to search, the key you're looking for and the key value to update (or add if it doesn't exist).

So I can pass in:

```
q = update_nested_dict(q, 'multi_match', 'operator', 'or')
q = update_nested_dict(q, 'multi_match', 'minimum_should_match', '80%')
```

And the "operator" value is updated, and the 'minimum_should_match' key/value is added under the 'multi_match' node, no matter what level it appears in the dictionary.

Might run into problems if the searched key exists in more than 1 place in the dictionary though.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own `setnesteditem` function once and for all:

```py
def setnesteditem(xs, path, newvalue):
    for i in path[:-1]:
        xs = xs[i]
    xs[path[-1]] = newvalue
```

And then call it on any nested structure, including lists and dicts:

```py
query = {'query': {'function_score': {'query': {'multi_match': {}}}}}

prefix = ('query', 'function_score', 'query', 'multi_match')
setnesteditem(query, (*prefix, 'operator'), 'or')
setnesteditem(query, (*prefix, 'minimum_should_match'), '80%')

print(query)
# {'query': {'function_score': {'query': {'multi_match': {'operator': 'or', 'minimum_should_match': '80%'}}}}}
```