# How to iterate through a nested dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested `python dictionary` data structure. I want to read its keys and values `without` using `collection` module. The data structure is like bellow.

```
d = {'dict1': {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}, 'dict2': {'baz': 3, 'quux': 4}}
```

I was trying to read the keys in the dictionary using the bellow way but getting error.

**Code**

```
for key, value in d:
    print(Key)
```

**Error**

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

So can anyone please explain the reason behind the error and how to iterate through the dictionary.

Comment: Do you want to read the nested keys and values as well ?

Comment: just write `d.items()`, it will work, by default on iterating the name of dict returns only the keys.                                                                                                               Hope it help. :)

Comment: yes. I want to read all the keys and values that include the nested keys an values

Comment: what is your desired output of the above dict d?

Comment: @SunilLulla  `dict1 foo 1 bar 2 \n dect2 baz 3 quux 4`

Comment: @Arijit Posted an answer for the requested output, have a look.

Comment: **See also:** [search for key in nested dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681301/search-for-a-key-in-a-nested-python-dictionary) -- [python dpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16508328/42223)

Comment: General answer of this question isn't answered here but is answered elsewhere: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756427/loop-through-all-nested-dictionary-values

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the requested output, the code goes like this

```
    d = {'dict1': {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}, 'dict2': {'baz': 3, 'quux': 4}}

    for k1,v1 in d.iteritems(): # the basic way
        temp = ""   
        temp+=k1
        for k2,v2 in v1.iteritems():
           temp = temp+" "+str(k2)+" "+str(v2)
        print temp
```

In place of `iteritems()` you can use `items()` as well, but `iteritems()` is much more efficient and returns an iterator.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The `iteritems` method does not exist for Python 3.

Answer (score 36):

The following will work with *multiple levels* of nested-dictionary:

```
def get_all_keys(d):
    for key, value in d.items():
        yield key
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            yield from get_all_keys(value)


d = {'dict1': {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}, 'dict2': {'dict3': {'baz': 3, 'quux': 4}}}
for x in get_all_keys(d):
    print(x)
```

This will give you:

```
dict1
foo
bar
dict2
dict3
baz
quux
```

Comment: Recursion can really save you a lot of time from manually specifying logic for each level of your nested dictionary

Answer (score 24):

`keys()` method returns a view object that displays a list of all the keys in the dictionary

Iterate nested dictionary:

```
d = {'dict1': {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}, 'dict2': {'baz': 3, 'quux': 4}}

for i in d.keys():
    print i
    for j in d[i].keys():
        print j
```

OR

```
for i in d:
    print i
    for j in d[i]:
        print j
```

output:

```
dict1 
foo
bar

dict2
baz 
quux
```

where `i` iterate main dictionary key and `j` iterate the nested dictionary key.

Answer (score 6):

you can iterate all keys and values of nested dictionary as following:

```
d = {'dict1': {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}, 'dict2': {'baz': 3, 'quux': 4}}

for i in d:
    for j, k in d[i].items():
        print(j,"->", k)
```

Your output looks like this -

```
foo -> 1
bar -> 2
baz -> 3
quux -> 4
```

Answer (score 4):

To get keys and values you need `dict.items()`:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    print(key)
```

If you want just the keys:

```
for key in d:
    print(key)
```

Comment: For python2 you could prefer `dict.iteritems()` instead, it is faster for this use case.

Comment: This is not an answer to "how to traverse a nested dict".

Answer (score 3):

Iterating through a dictionary only gives you the keys.

You told python to expect a bunch of tuples, and it tried to unpack something that wasn't a tuple (your code is set up to expect each iterated item to be of the form `(key,value)`, which was not the case (you were simply getting `key` on each iteration).

You also tried to print `Key`, which is not the same as `key`, which would have led to a `NameError`.

```
for key in d:
    print(key)
```

should work.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `benedict` (a `dict` subclass) and the **traverse** utility method:

Installation: `pip install python-benedict`

```
from benedict import benedict

d = benedict({'dict1': {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}, 'dict2': {'baz': 3, 'quux': 4}})

def traverse_item(dct, key, value):
   print('key: {} - value: {}'.format(key, value))

d.traverse(traverse_item)
```

Documentation: https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/python-benedict

Note: I am the author of this project.

Comment: Checked it out and seems it's perfect for NoSql data parsing. Perfect Package!!

Answer (score 2):

if given dictionary pattern has monotone format and keys are known

```
dict_ = {'0': {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}, '1': {'foo': 3, 'bar': 4}}
for key, val in dict_.items():
    if isinstance(val, dict):
        print(val.get('foo'))
        print(val.get('bar'))
```

in this case we can skip nested loop

Answer (score 1):

```
def print_all(df):
 #iterates through a nested dict and prints all values
 for key in df.keys():
         if type(df[key]) == dict:
                 print_all(df[key])
                 
         else:
               print(key,':',df[key])


example
ds = {'dict1': {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2,'dict2': {'dict3': {'baz': 3, 'quux': 4}}}, 'dict2': {'dict3': {'baz': 3, 'quux': 4}}}

print_all(ds)

output

foo : 1
bar : 2
baz : 3
quux : 4
baz : 3
quux : 4
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).